Is there a way to prevent phone calls from being accepted with the screen locked?
I tried in many ways to prevent phone calls from being accepted with the screen locked on my Samsung, but there was no such thing.
Why? Well, WhatsApp SMS codes can be received through phone calls, and many other 2FA services as well support phone calls.

A well designed service allows you to protect your account, making it not possible to take over the account even by receiving SMS or phone calls. Not sure if WhatsApp support this  Signal does (account PIN).

@Robert unfortunately the majority of services are not well designed. Even if they were, allowing people to answer calls on my phone if stolen is never a good idea

If I understand correctly, your needs may be met by rejecting calls when your device is locked. If automation is acceptable, try this macro using     MacroDroid app// I haven't tested this but I guess it should work fine since I run a similar macro that rejects all no-contact calls (spam and unwanted business calls)// This app is free upto 5 macros. It asks for a lot of permissions which I grant since I know they are needed and trust the developer

Many answers on this site using MacroDroid using this app including some by me

IDK if you've tried it but you could check with constraint as "screen off" too

I can see that you want to avoid the phone call from being answered while the screen is locked on your Samsung phone. Well, I got a Samsung phone too and I know that there is no built-it setting option for this problem.
Actually, the services like WhatsApp or even other authentication systems via phone might choose to simply call you to deliver the codes and blocking such calls would in fact prevent the proper working of these features. These phone calls are sometimes meant for security reasons so that the Android can process the call even if the screen is locked.
I use an application "Call Blocker" for this and it working on my Galaxy M21. It blocks incoming calls when the screen is locked. Also provides other blocking spam numbers, setting custom call filters, and managing call settings future for privacy. Test it out and see if it works on your phone.
